# How would I override display output from a ruby method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to override output that is displayed on a page only if it meets the conditional of my Ruby method.

This page is supposed to display a user that edits an activity only if the activity parameters have a role assigned.

---

Here is a sample of the method:

```
  def activity_by_role(data)
    if !data.include?(:role)
      content_tag(:div, content_tag(:p, "Not Permitted"), class: "strong")
    end
  end
```

I am calling the method in a view using this code:

```
  <%= render_activity activity unless activity_by_role(activity.parameters) %> | created at <%= activity.created_at %>
```

This is the output I am receiving follows:
[image]

Where there is a blank after the user name I would like it to show "Not Permitted". Where it shows edited "item" is how that activity output should be displayed.

Any suggestions on how to display the text "Not Permitted" if the activity parameters do not meet the conditional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly your issue, you can simply render both possibilities in the view helper:

```
# helper:
def render_activity_by_role(activity)
  if activity.parameters.include?(:role)
    render_activity(activity)
  else
    content_tag(:div, content_tag(:p, "Not Permitted"), class: "strong")
  end
end

# view:
<%= render_activity_by_role(activity) %> | created at <%= activity.created_at %>
```

Comment: perfect, seems so obvious now that I see it. Thank you!